# Proving how to reduce a Brownian walk on a plane to a line (2D to 1D)

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, random-walk, dimension-theory-analysis

I have a Brownian motion on a plane and would like to find the time of when it is expected to hit a set of parallel lines, i.e the hitting time. In order to do so, I understand that I can reduce the problem to a single dimension in order to simplify calculations, after which the Brownian motion will become a one-dimensional random walk I think. But how can I prove that this is possible? Reading on the Internet, I saw that Brownian motions are invariant under rotations (although I have no proof of that) and that I can possibly use an orthogonal projection (not sure if that is true or applicable, maybe it was just for finding the hitting time when circles are involved). Can someone illustrate how this works?

Comment: you can use stratonovich calculus, it  obeys same rule as of  newtonian calculus  .

Comment: @Boris Could you please illustrate how that would work in finding the hitting time?

Comment: Invariance of standard 2-D Brownian motion under rotations around it's origin  follows from rotational invariance of the joint distribution of two centered i.i.d. Normals. Can you show this latter fact? It's quite easy. Once you align the $x$-axis parallel to the corridor, you only have to worry about 1 Brownian motion and you can repeteadly (infinitely many times to be exact) apply reflection principle.

Comment: @A.S. Thanks I understand some of this, but what do you mean by applying reflection principle infinitely many times? Could you possibly clarify?

Comment: I misread what you were asked to do (I was refering to finding $P(\tau_{-a,b}>t)$). The result for you 1-D question is $E\tau_{-a,b}=ab$.

Comment: @A.S. I guess that's for the case when the Brownian motion is between two parallel lines. Is there a theorem for this fact?

Comment: Ways to see it: a) Show that it ($E\tau^x_{-a,b}=(b-x)(x-a)$) is true for a Simple Random Walk (for integer $a,b,x$) and take the limiting process. b) Consider generator of the Brownian motion to get $$\frac 1 2\frac {\partial \tau^x_{-a,b}}{\partial x}=-1$$ with two boundary conditions $\tau^{x}_{-a,b}=0$ at $x=-a,b$ yielding the same formula a above. c) Note that if you scale $a$ and $b$ by factor $c$, $E\tau$ must get scaled by $c^2$. At the same time, if either one of $a$ and $b$ is $0$, $E\tau=0$. This suggests that the answer is $E\tau \propto ab$.

Comment: @A.S. I understand, thanks. Feel free to post what you have commented here as an answer. Just to be clear, what you mean is that when you have aligned the lines next to the $x$-axis, the Brownian motion is one-dimensional and hence the limit of a random walk in one dimension?